# Sql: Unpivot with dynamic column list

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to do some unpivoting in sql, converting key-values into a list of IDs. The Column from the table is dynamic and will change weekly (mayhaps even daily).
Where there maybe more KEY Columns and values possibilities.

**DATABASE.PUBLIC.IMPORT_TABLE**

```
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
| SOURCE_ID | KEY1   | KEY2   | [KEY3] |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
| 0001      | TRUE   | FALSE  | [TBD]  |
| 0002      | TRUE   | FALSE  | [TBD]  |
| 0003      | TRUE   | TRUE   | [TBD]  |
| 0004      | TRUE   | TRUE   | [TBD]  |
| 0005      | FALSE  | TRUE   | [TBD]  |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

To manage the possible combinations there is a table which manages the key-value pairs, and gives them an ID. This table is used to manage the Columns I am interested in. Where sometimes if there there are additional Columns added and not in this table it will be excluded.

**DATABASE.PUBLIC.KEY_VALUE_TABLE**

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| KEY       | VALUE  | KV_ID  |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| KEY1      | TRUE   | AAA    |
| KEY1      | FALSE  | BBB    |
| KEY2      | TRUE   | CCC    |
| KEY2      | FALSE  | DDD    |
| [KEY3]    | [TRUE] | [EEE]  |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Using the following query. I am able to achieve the unpivot I am looking for. However it does not take into account changes in dynamic changes for KEY_VALUE_TABLE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DATABASE.PUBLIC.FINAL_TABLE AS
SELECT SOURCE_ID
      ,LISTAGG(DISTINCT b.KV_ID, ',') within group (order by b.KV_ID desc) AS KV_ID
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT SOURCE_ID, KEY, VALUE from DATABASE.PUBLIC.IMPORT_TABLE
    UNPIVOT(VALUE for KEY in (KEY1,KEY2))
) a
LEFT JOIN DATABASE.PUBLIC.KEY_VALUE_TABLE b
ON (a.KEY=b.KEY AND a.VALUE=b.VALUE)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Where the results look like the following
**DATABASE.PUBLIC.FINAL_TABLE**

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| SOURCE_ID | KV_ID           |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 0001      | AAA,DDD         |
| 0002      | AAA,DDD         |
| 0003      | AAA,CCC         |
| 0004      | AAA,CCC         |
| 0005      | BBB,CCC         |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Is there a way to have the `UNPIVOT(VALUE for KEY in (KEY1,KEY2))`

to something like `UNPIVOT(VALUE for KEY in (SELECT DISTINCT KEY FROM KEY_VALUE_TABLE))`. Note I already tried the latter and it does not work.
SQL has an issue using `SELECT` within the UNPIVOT

I have also tried using `UNPIVOT(VALUE for KEY in ($KEY_LIST))`
Where my variable is `SET KEY_LIST = '[KEY1,KEY2]'`
=> `SET KEY_LIST = (SELECT listagg(KEY, ',') as my_strings FROM DATABASE.PUBLIC.KEY_VALUE_TABLE)`
SQL has a limit on the size of variables.

Any Advice would be appreciated.
My next step is to create a Stored Procedure or a Function. Which takes in external variables. via javascript or something similar.

Comment: you have to put your query in stored procedure , there you can create key in logic in some variable.